# How to manage two Cassandra sessions using spring data cassandra with spring boot 2.7.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

In My Application, Using the below technologies

```
Spring boot 2.7.x
spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra 2.7.x
spring batch 5. x
java 11
```

```
Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.package1"},
    cassandraTemplateRef = "cassandraTemplate1",
    repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CassandraRepositoryWithTtlFactoryBean.class
)
public class CassandraConfigurationCluster1 extends CassandraConfiguration {
```

```
Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.package2"},
    cassandraTemplateRef = "cassandraTemplate2",
    repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CassandraRepositoryWithTtlFactoryBean.class
)
public class CassandraConfigurationCluster2 extends CassandraConfiguration {
```

and with that I have created two beans for `CassandraAdminTemplate` ( not sure I was using CassandraTemplate from spring boot 2.2.x but its changed to something else in 2.7.x

```
   @Bean("session1")
  public CqlSessionFactoryBean session() {
    return new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
  }

  @Bean("cassandraTemplate1")
  public CassandraAdminOperations cassandraTemplate(
          @Qualifier("session1")  final CqlSessionFactoryBean session) {
    return new CassandraAdminTemplate(session.getObject(), cassandraConverter());
  }
```

```
@Bean("session2")
  public CqlSessionFactoryBean session() {
    return new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
  }

  @Bean("cassandraTemplate2")
  public CassandraAdminOperations cassandraTemplate(
          @Qualifier("session2")  final CqlSessionFactoryBean session) {
    return new CassandraAdminTemplate(session.getObject(), cassandraConverter());
  }
```

But I am getting error

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [*/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [*/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: session1,session2","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext"}

I know this error but I don't know what else should I use it instead to managed two separate Cassandra connections

Thanks

Comment: Please add the full exception you get instead of a snippet.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum added exception. I am mostly looking to create two cassandraTemplate bean for two different sessions (to connect to 2 clusters) but did not find a way in 2.7.x

Comment: That is still just a snippet there should be more to the stacktrace, like the indication where this is being attempted.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added full logs .. now it will be clear to understand what I am looking for

Comment: Please don't use quotes to add code/stacktrace they become totally unreadable. Pleae use code tags. The problem is the `CassandraConfiguration` you are extending, don't or at least that exposes beans as well that interfere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create two unique sessions to connect to two different keyspaces by adding below code

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(
basePackages = {"com.package1"},
cassandraTemplateRef = "cassandraTemplate1",
repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CassandraRepositoryWithTtlFactoryBean.class
)
public class CassandraConfigurationCluster1 extends CassandraConfiguration {

@Primary
@Bean("session1")
public SessionFactoryFactoryBean cassandraSessionFactory(CqlSession cqlSession) {
SessionFactoryFactoryBean bean = new SessionFactoryFactoryBean();
bean.setSession(cqlSession);
  bean.setConverter((CassandraConverter)this.requireBeanOfType(CassandraConverter.class));
bean.setKeyspaceCleaner(this.keyspaceCleaner());
bean.setKeyspacePopulator(this.keyspacePopulator());
bean.setSchemaAction(this.getSchemaAction());
return bean;
}

@Bean("cassandraTemplate1")
public CassandraAdminOperations cassandraTemplate(
      @Qualifier("session1")  final SessionFactoryFactoryBean session) throws Exception {
return new CassandraAdminTemplate(session.getObject(), cassandraConverter());
}
```

For second session

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(
basePackages = {"com.package2"},
cassandraTemplateRef = "cassandraTemplate2",
repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CassandraRepositoryWithTtlFactoryBean.class
)
public class CassandraConfigurationCluster2 extends CassandraConfiguration {    

@Bean("session2")
public SessionFactoryFactoryBean cassandraSessionFactory(CqlSession cqlSession) {
SessionFactoryFactoryBean bean = new SessionFactoryFactoryBean();
bean.setSession(cqlSession);
  bean.setConverter((CassandraConverter)this.requireBeanOfType(CassandraConverter.class));
bean.setKeyspaceCleaner(this.keyspaceCleaner());
bean.setKeyspacePopulator(this.keyspacePopulator());
bean.setSchemaAction(this.getSchemaAction());
return bean;
}

@Bean("cassandraTemplate2")
public CassandraAdminOperations cassandraTemplate(
      @Qualifier("session2")  final SessionFactoryFactoryBean session) throws Exception {
return new CassandraAdminTemplate(session.getObject(), cassandraConverter());
}
```

with this I could connect to two clusters without any issues